# How to get remote image height and width in Appcelerator Titanium

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I am posting sample code below please any help me

```
var bb_CoverPageImage = Ti.UI.createImageView({
    width : '100%',
    image : '',
    categoryName : magazinePagesList[i].categoryName,
    lengthId : magazinePagesList.length,
});

bb_CoverPageImage.image = L('Site_URL_Images') + magazinePagesList[i].imagePreviewUrl.replace(/\s/g, '%20');    

coverScrollView.add(bb_CoverPageImage);
```

Answer (score 5):

Though you have not mentioned why you need image width/height of remote image, but there can be basically 3 ways to get the width/height of any remote image.

---

**Solution 1:**

You can either ask your backend devs to provide you the image width & height as separate parameters.

---

**Solution 2:**

You can use **[Ti.UI.ImageView's load event](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.ImageView-event-load)** to wait till your image is loaded & then you can use a code similar like this:

```
imageview.addEventListener('load', function(e) {
    var image = imageview.toBlob();
    var h = image.height;
    var w = image.width;
});
```

This method forces that you can get width/height only after the image is loaded in ImageView.

---

**Solution 3:**

You can use web-service to download image & get further values:

```
var client = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient({
    onload: function(e) {
        var image = this.responseData;
        var h = image.height;
        var w = image.width;

        bb_CoverPageImage.image = image;
    },
    onerror: function(e) {}
});
client.open("GET", magazinePagesList[i].imagePreviewUrl);
client.send();
```